# Is gauge group infinite dimensional Lie group?

Tags: lie-groups, principal-bundles, gauge-theory

Let $P$ be a smooth principal bundle on a manifold $M$ with a structure Lie group $G$. Then we define the gauge group $\mathcal{G}$ by the automorphism group of $P$, that is, the group of diffeomorphisms on $P$ which preserve the fiber and the action of $G$. [This pdf](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/journal-of-geometry-and-symmetry-in-physics/volume-1/issue-none/Infinite-Dimentional-Lie-Groups-with-Applications-to-Mathematical-Physics/10.7546/jgsp-1-2004-54-120.full) says that the gauge group is a Hilbert Lie group. Is it true? And what is its Lie algebra?

Comment: Yes, it is an infinite dimensional Lie group. The Lie algebra is constructed in the same way starting from the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ of $G$. In particular two Lie groups with the same Lie algebras lead to gauge groups whose Lie algebras are isomorphic. Thus notice that the Lie algebra of a gauge group does not have information about large gauge transformations, which indeed depend on the global structure of $G$.

Comment: Its Lie algebra is the vector space of vertical vector fields on $P$.

Comment: @Andrea Antinucci Could you tell me references including the proof?

Comment: @s.h The book "Gauge Theory and the Topology of Four-Manifolds" contains an extensive series of lectures by John Morgan in which all these facts are well explained.

Answer (score 0):

the reason why a gauge field is in the Lie algebra of a gauge group $G$ is that we have to cancel out the term which comes from the kinetic term by acting gauge transformation.
For simplification I want to use the $F_{\mu \nu}$. I know this transforms as
$$
F_{\mu \nu} \rightarrow g F_{\mu \nu} g^{-1}
$$
and it's called adjoint representation $(g \in G)$.
The field strength $F_{\mu \nu}$ is a (local representation of) a Lie-algebra valued two-form. In components, it is often written as $F_{\mu \nu}^a$, where the $\mu \nu$ are the space-time indices (making it a two-form) and a is the Lie-algebra index. As such, it is indeed in the Lie-algebra.

However, it is not any Lie-algebra valued two form. Instead, it is the (local representation of) the covariant derivative of a special one-form, the connection one-form (whose local representation is usually denoted by $A_\mu$ ). This necessarily transforms in the adjoint representation. An intuitive reasoning for this can be found in this [question (1)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/462723/why-quarks-in-the-fundamental-and-gluons-in-the-adjoint).
This is the mathematical viewpoint. The physical viewpoint is that the adjoint rep gives the "correct" transformation, simply because of the way we have defined the field strength in nonabelian gauge theories. Specifically, the field strength is defined as (this definition comes from the differential geometry picture sketched above):
$$
F_{\mu \nu}=\partial_\mu A_\nu-\partial_\nu A_\mu-i\left[A_\nu, A_\mu\right]
$$

And if you perform a gauge transformation of this object (as is done e.g. [here (2)](https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/pdf/10.1142/9789813234192_0001), you find that it transforms in the adjoint representation.

Comment: This is not answering the question, although it's a good illustration of what a mathematician calls a "gauge group" and what a physicist calls a  "gauge group". What you're calling the gauge group is typically called the "structure group" in mathematics literature. The gauge group is the group of bundle automorphisms. Anyway, I think you have misunderstood the question.